# AWS toolkit install error

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to install AWS toolkit by following the [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/setup-install.html). However, I am getting the following error with the latest version:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Core (Required) 2.3.1.v201702201547 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.feature.feature.group 2.3.1.v201702201547)
Missing requirement: AWS Toolkit Core 2.3.1.v201702201547 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.core 2.3.1.v201702201547) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.1' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Core (Required) 2.3.1.v201702201547 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.feature.feature.group 2.3.1.v201702201547)
To: com.amazonaws.eclipse.core [2.3.1.v201702201547]
```

I am using Eclipse Kepler version. I am however, able to install the older versions of AWS toolkit core. Also, for some reason, the `.metadata/.plugins/com.amazonaws.eclipse.core/` directory in workspace doesn't have `aws-sdk-java` directory which is expected. Are these two related? Any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because of your eclipse version.

You should just update your eclipse with a newer version than kepler.